# problema com uma script

Tags: php, javascript, html

bom estou fazendo um carrinho e quando não tem a quantidade em estoque a script retorna um error
porém mesmo aparecendo o error está alterando o valor total:
fotos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando adiciona 3 itens 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando adicionado mais de 1 ta somando o valor total e não era pra fazer isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo html:

```
<?php
                $sessao = $_SESSION['pedido'];
                $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM carrinho_temporario WHERE temporario_sessao =:ses");
                $consulta -> bindValue(':ses', $sessao);
                $consulta -> execute();

                $total = 0;
                $linhas = $consulta -> rowCount();
                foreach($consulta as $mostra):
                $total += $mostra['temporario_preco'];

                    $prod = $mostra['temporario_produto'];
                    $consultar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM homesite WHERE id_skin =:prod");
                    $consultar -> bindValue(':prod', $prod);
                    $consultar -> execute();
                    foreach($consultar as $mostrar):
                        $produtos = $mostrar['skin_nome'];
            ?>

                <div class="wrapper_child">
                <div id="colorx" class="tab">
                <h3 class="text-center align-middle"><img class="imgcar" src="images/<?= $mostrar['skin_img']?>"></h3>
                </div>

                <div id="gallery" class="tab">
                <h3 class="text-center align-middle"><strong><p class="nomecar"><?= $produtos; ?></p></strong></h3>
                </div>

                <div id="about" class="tab">
                <h3 class="text-center align-middle">
                <form method="post">                    
                    <input type="text" value="<?= $mostrar['skin_quantidade']?>" name="1" id="estoque" style="display:none;">
                    <input type="text" value="<?= $mostrar['skin_preco'];?>" name="preco" id="estoque" style="display:none;">
                    <input type="number" name="id"  value="<?= $mostra['temporario_id']?>" style="display:none;">
                    <input type="number" name="quantidade"  value="<?= $mostra['temporario_quantidade']?>" class="qtdchange" id="qtd" onchange="acrescentar()">
                    <button class="color-white link-bgcolor-green-dark-b" name="alterar" value="Alterar"> Alterar</button></h3>
                    <p class="text-center font-text-light"><a href="excluir-produto.php?ref=<?= $mostra['temporario_id']?>" class="color-dark-full">Excluir Produto</a></p>
                    <span id="resultado"></span>
                </div>

                <div id="contacts" class="tab">
                <strong><p class="skinpreco"><?= $mostrar['skin_preco']?></p> </strong>
                </div>
                <div id="contactx" class="tab">
                <strong><p class="skinprecototal">R$ <?=  number_format($mostra['temporario_preco'], 2,',','.');?></p></p></strong>
                </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    var myVar = setInterval(acrescentar, 1000);
                    function acrescentar () {
                        var qtd = document.getElementById( 'qtd' );
                        var estoque = document.getElementById( 'estoque' );
                        var resultado = document.getElementById( 'resultado' );

                        var valor_qtd = qtd.value;
                        var valor_est = parseInt( estoque.value ) ;


                        if(valor_qtd <= valor_est && valor_qtd >= 0){
                            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "";

                        }else if(valor_qtd < 0){
                            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Estoque Negativo Inexistente!";
                        }else{
                            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Estoque Insuficiente! temos apenas: "+valor_est+ "produtos";
                        }

                    }
                    </script>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['alterar'])):
                            $qtde = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'quantidade');
                            $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'id');
                            $preco = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'preco');

                            echo '<script>window.location="alterar.php?qtd='.$qtde.'&preco='.$preco.'&ref='.$id.'"</script>';
                        endif;
                    ?>

            <?php endforeach; endforeach; ?>
              </div>
```

parte da script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var myVar = setInterval(acrescentar, 1000);
            function acrescentar () {
                var qtd = document.getElementById( 'qtd' );
                var estoque = document.getElementById( 'estoque' );
                var resultado = document.getElementById( 'resultado' );

                var valor_qtd = qtd.value;
                var valor_est = parseInt( estoque.value ) ;


                if(valor_qtd <= valor_est && valor_qtd >= 0){
                    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "";

                }else if(valor_qtd < 0){
                    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Estoque Negativo Inexistente!";
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Estoque Insuficiente! temos apenas: "+valor_est+ "produtos";
                }

            }
            </script>
```

Comment: Onde é alterado o valor, qual função?

Comment: como assim? n entendi.